# lvalue in assignment too complex

Tags: glsl

Following code causes a glsl error: lvalue in assignment too complex

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    if(Lgt.lights[i].position.w == 0.0)
    {
        LightDir[i] = normalize(vec3(Lgt.lights[i].position));
        ViewDir[i] = normalize(cameraWorldPosition - worldPosition);
    }
    else
    {
        LightDir[i] = normalize(vec3(Lgt.lights[i].position) - worldPosition);
        ViewDir[i] = normalize(cameraWorldPosition - worldPosition);
    }
}
```

But in the other shader program an identical piece of code works fine. When the code doesn't contain if statement, for example

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    LightDir[i] = normalize(vec3(Lgt.lights[i].position) - worldPosition);
    ViewDir[i] = normalize(cameraWorldPosition - worldPosition);
}
```

everything is ok, but when I use multiplication:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
     LightDir[i] = LocalMat * normalize(vec3(Lgt.lights[i].position) - worldPosition);
     ViewDir[i] = LocalMat * normalize(cameraWorldPosition - worldPosition);
}
```

I get that error again. Can anyone tell what is going on ?

Comment: What driver version, what GPU?

Comment: nvlddmkm 8.17.13.142(ForceWare 301.42)/Win7, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 560 Ti

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're running on a GPU/driver combination that doesn't allow indexed assignments.  So in order to compile the code, it will need to completely unroll the loop, changing all the indexes in the lvalues into constants.  This apparently happens in some cases, but not all.

If you're using an Nvidia GPU/driver, you might try putting `#pragma optionNV unroll all` in the top of your shader program to force full unrolling of all loops -- but that might cause problems if you have other loops that shouldn't be unrolled.

Comment: I don't get that error when I use #pragma optionNV unroll all.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this error, but my cause was different.

It turns out I had a hard coded maximum index in my for loop which was bigger than the array I was trying to assign to. My guess is that the compiler got confused when attempting to unfold and there were not enough indices for the lvalue.